# Javascript data load - how to ignore headers and verify data

Tags: javascript

I am loading a CSV file that looks like this in JavaScript:

```
user_id, aligned_audio_onset_sec, x, y
1, 1.3 , 0.3, 0.5
1, 5, 0.9, 0.3
3, 4, 0.5, 0.5
```

With this script:

```
$(function() {

var VAdata = $.get("./VAdata.data", function(data) {
  VAdata = data.split(/\r?\n/).map(pair => pair.split(/,/).map(Number));

  $('#log').text(JSON.stringify(VAdata));

  });
});
```

It works well, except it does not ignore the headers, but I can't figure out how to do that. I was also wondering if I could do a check to see if all rows have a length of 4 and remove those that don't. (I can only think of copying row by row and only including those with full length.)

The log div outputs:

```
[[null,null,null,null],[1,1.3,0.3,0.5],[1,5,0.9,0.3],[3,4,0.5,0.5],[0]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method for that.

```
VAdata = data
          .split(/\r?\n/)
          .filter((v, i) => i && v.split(/,/).length >= 4)
          .map(pair => pair.split(/,/)
          .map(Number));
```

```js
var data = 'user_id, aligned_audio_onset_sec, x, y\n1, 1.3 , 0.3, 0.5\n1, 5, 0.9, 0.3\n3, 4, 0.5, 0.5';

var VAdata = data
  .split(/\r?\n/)
  .filter((v, i) => i && v.split(/,/).length >= 4)
  .map(pair => pair.split(/,/)
    .map(Number));

console.log(VAdata);
```

Where `i && pair.split(/,/).length >= 4` :

1. `i` would be [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) when `0` first element would be ignored.
2. `v.split(/,/).length >= 4` would help to filter out full length elements.

---

You can use a simple for loop or [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to reduce the number of iterations.

```
VAdata = [];
data.split(/\r?\n/)
    .forEach((pair, i) => { 
       let spl = pair.split(/,/);
       i && spl.length >= 4 && VAdata.push(spl.map(Number))
    });
```

```js
var data = 'user_id, aligned_audio_onset_sec, x, y\n1, 1.3 , 0.3, 0.5\n1, 5, 0.9, 0.3\n3, 4, 0.5, 0.5';

var VAdata = [];
data.split(/\r?\n/)
  .forEach((pair, i) => {
    let spl = pair.split(/,/);
    i && spl.length >= 4 && VAdata.push(spl.map(Number))
  });

console.log(VAdata)
```

If you want to treat `NaN` value as `0` then use:

```
...push(spl.map(v => Number(v) || 0))
```

Comment: I wondered for a minute where you could possibly ignore the first row here. Really clever solution

Answer (score 1):

Use `.slice(1)` to remove the headers from the list of arrays, and then use `.filter(e => e.length === 4)` to ensure that only arrays with four elements are included in the final result:

### Your Code

```js
$.get("./VAdata.data", function (data) {
  var VAdata = data
    .split(/\r?\n/)
    .slice(1)
    .map(pair => pair
      .split(/,/)
      .map(Number)
    ).filter(e => e.length === 4)
    
  $(function() {
    $('#log').text(JSON.stringify(VAdata))
  })
})
```

### Demo Snippet

```js
var data = 'user_id, aligned_audio_onset_sec, x, y\n1, 1.3 , 0.3, 0.5\n1, 5, 0.9, 0.3\n3, 4, 0.5, 0.5'

console.log(data)

var VAdata = data
  .split(/\r?\n/)
  .slice(1)
  .map(pair => pair
    .split(/,/)
    .map(Number)
  ).filter(e => e.length === 4)

$(function() {
  console.log(VAdata)
  $('#log').text(JSON.stringify(VAdata))
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="log"></pre>
```